# Javascript Input field value undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The problem which i have is that i can't access the value of one of my text field. I know that when the document is initially loaded the value would be undefined. But when i am accessing value of input field when i have clicked on submit then i must get exact entered string in text box.

```
$("#foo").submit(function(event)
```

But even after this event listener i can't access the value.

```
console.log(comment_value);
```

always shows undefined. I also used the jquery version of val() function but of no help.

Please guide. Thank you

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){                
        $("#foo").submit(function(event){           
          var comment_value = document.getElementById("newComment").value;        
          console.log(comment_value);

          event.preventDefault();
          // $("#newcommentblock").html(&#039;<img src="a.gif"/>&#039;);                  

          request = $.ajax({
            url: "getcomment.php",
            type: "POST",
            timeout:30000,  
            dataType: "text", 
            data:{getquestionid: 12, getcomment: "comment_value"}               
          });

          alert("inside script");

          request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

          console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
          //$("#comments").html(response);              
        });        

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){               
          console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
        });        

        request.always(function () {});

        console.log("hi inside");           
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <h1> 
      question: <br> jisofqw<br>        
    </h1>

     <p id = "comments">        
      comments <br>
    </p>

    Type your comment here
    <div id = "newcommentblock">
      <p id = "newComment">  </p>
      <form  id = "foo" name = "commentbox" action = "#" >
        <input type = "text" id ="newComment"   name = "newComment">
        <input type = "submit" value = "post a comment">
      </form>
    </div>

    <p id = "answer">
      answer
    </p>        
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have duplicate id. it will pick only the first element appearing in DOM which happens to be a `p` tag and it is not an input field.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is here

```
<p id="newComment"></p>
```

Provide a different **ID** to `<p>` tag .

Comment: Please have a read of the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).